# While trying sql query got error as,"table space cannot be accessed"

Tags: db2

In DB2, when using select query, getting error as ,"an object 58, table space cannot be accessed"

Comment: Did you google this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error description should be longer, and you can find which table by looking at the catalog (syscat.tables, syscat.tablespaces)